# How to get string from an EditText?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

At the bottom of "buttonClicked" function I am trying to get the string from my EditText but it says "**can't resolve "number**". I don't understand why it can't.

```
public class TopFragment extends Fragment {
 TopFragmentListener activityListener;

public interface TopFragmentListener{
    void createFrament(String numberOfFragments);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
   try{
        activityListener = (TopFragmentListener) context;
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException (context.toString());
    }

}

 @Nullable
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);

     final Button btnAdd = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
     EditText number = view.findViewById(R.id.number);
   btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonClicked(v);
        }
     });

    return view;
 }

 public void buttonClicked(View view) {
     activityListener.createFrament(number.getText);
 } }
```

Comment: use number.getText.toString();

Comment: Take a look at "scope" in java

Comment: move this line ` activityListener.createFrament(number.getText().toString());` to onClick() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare number as global :

```
EditText number;
```

Then in your function buttonClicked() :

```
number.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like :

```
number.getText().toString();
```

And **EditText number** to be declared globally.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, declare the number as **global**, and then it should be like :

```
number.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your EditText on your `onCreate`. Please add your declaration to global it's something like `EditText number`.

Then in your function call this :

`number.getText().toString()`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you method     `void createFrament(String numberOfFragments);`  is required String as parameter. so while calling this method use

```
 activityListener.createFrament(number.getText.toString());
```

instead of

```
 activityListener.createFrament(number.getText);
```